# Split Birth Date

Tags: php, regex

I have some birth dates stored in mm/dd/yyyy format. Ex: 05/20/1987

I have a form to edit the birth date and I would like to split up the month, day, and year so I can echo them separately in some select drop downs.

```
<?php $birthdate = "05/20/1987"; ?>

<select name="dob_month">
<option value="<?php echo $month; ?>"></option>
</select>

<select name="dob_day">
<option value="<?php echo $day; ?>"></option>
</select>

<select name="dob_year">
<option value="<?php echo $year; ?>"></option>
</select>
```

So with the birthdate given above, it would look like this:

```
<select name="dob_month">
<option value="05"></option>
</select>

<select name="dob_day">
<option value="20"></option>
</select>

<select name="dob_year">
<option value="1987"></option>
</select>
```

Is regex the correct solution?

Comment: so where is the issue? split it based on `/`

Comment: No, not regex for this.

Comment: I would use `DateTime` class to get the date and then you can easily format it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try with:

```
list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $birthdate);
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked beautifully.

Answer (score 4):

list($month, $day, $year) = explode('/', $birthdate);

Answer (score 0):

If your format is fixed and you don't need to validate the date, you can directly use `substr`:

```
echo substr($birthdate,0,2); // month
echo substr($birthdate,3,2); // day
echo substr($birthdate,6,4); // year
```